# why my packages is showing folder structure after set into flat in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, directory

My package is showing folder structure after set in flat in Eclipse:

[image]

How to fix it?

`.classpath` file:
[image]

`.project` file:
[image]

Comment: You have `src/main/resources` as source folder, but also its parent folder `src/main`  - probable by mistake - as source folder. Does right-clicking the project folder and choosing _Maven > Update Project..._ fix your issue?

Comment: I have updated the project as Maven > Update Project but still it is showing same as folder .

Comment: Does right-clicking `src/main` and choosing _Build Path > Remove from Build Path_ help? Are there errors shown in your `pom.xml`? Please show your `pom.xml` and your `.classpath` files.

Comment: I shared the pom.xml file and .classpath file

Comment: `.classpath` does not have a `src/main` folder in contrast to the screenshot. That's strange. Please add the content of your `pom.xml` (not `.project`) as text (not as image) to your question.

Comment: I already have the content in pom.xml file but still same folder structure is coming

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. How can this be reproduced? According to the cropped screenshot there are errors. Which errors?

Comment: The error is in .classfile it should have all the jar files/dependency right?

Comment: Your `.classpath` file correctly refers to the Maven dependencies via `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">`. The entry for JUnit 3.8.1 does not seem correct to me since all dependencies should derived by the mentioned entry from your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Yeah I got the solution, Thanks for your help @howlger.